# Dynamic Bootstrap Tables Columns Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

**Hi Team,
Actually I just Wanted to Render Data Like
Expecting Values like Given Below:-**

[image]

**But Coming Values Like Given Below:-**

[image]

** Im Using this in my Laravel Project Here Is My Code:-**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Skills</th>
      <th scope="col">Abilities</th>
      <th scope="col">Work Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Work Context</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
    $sub_skill = ["Skill 1","skill 2"];
    $sub_abilities = ["Ability 1","Ability 2","Ability 3","Ability 4","Ability 5","Ability 6"];
    $sub_workactivity = ["workactivity 1","workactivity 2"];
    $sub_workcontext = ["workcontext 1","workcontext 2", "workcontext 3"];
?>
<tbody>
    @foreach($sub_skill as $skill_key=>$skill_value)
           <tr>
               <td>{{ $skill_value }}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
    @endforeach
       @foreach($sub_abilities as $abilities_key=>$abilities_value)
           <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $abilities_value }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
       @foreach($sub_workactivity as $sub_workactivity_key=>$sub_workactivity_value)
           <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $sub_workactivity_value }}</td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
       @foreach($sub_workcontext as $workcontext_key=>$workcontext_value)
           <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $workcontext_value }}</td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Please Help me.
Thanks Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one loop and each iteration is one row. So calculate the maximum length of all collections and use a for loop with this length.

```
//pseudo code
@for($i=0; $i<$max_length; $i++)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ isset($sub_skill[$i]) ? $sub_skill[$i] : '' }}</td>
           <td>{{ isset($sub_abilities[$i]) ? $sub_abilities[$i] : '' }}</td>
           <td>{{ isset($sub_workactivity[$i]) ? $sub_workactivity[$i] : '' }}</td>
           <td>{{ isset($sub_workcontext[$i]) ? $sub_workcontext[$i] : '' }}</td>
       </tr>
@endfor
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Response Sir,
                                              I think it may be use here for Loop?

Comment: You're welcome, and of course you're right. It should be a for loop. I edited my suggestion.